# Fail to use statement IF in Selenium

Tags: ruby, if-statement, selenium, rspec, selenium-webdriver

Currently I'm trying use a statement IF (If a button appears in the page, then run the IF), see the method **Login in the system**:

If the button doesn't appear in the page, I would like to run the next method **Remove and add new expense**

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "rspec"
require "rspec/expectations"

describe "#Add simple expense and after add a receipt", :suitee => true do

before(:all) do
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
  @base_url = "http://sitetest.com"
  @driver.manage.window.maximize
end

it "Login in the system" do
  @driver.get(@base_url)
  @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys "rafael@gmail.com"
  @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").send_keys "123456"
  @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    if(@driver.find_element(:css, ".btn.btn-lg.btn-success.btn-block").displayed?)
        @driver.find_element(:css, ".btn.btn-lg.btn-success.btn-block").click
        @driver.find_element(:css, ".introjs-button.introjs-skipbutton").click
        @driver.find_element(:css, ".i.i-pencil").click
    end
end

it "Remove and add new expense" do
  begin 
    while(@driver.find_element(:css, ".i.i-pencil.icon").displayed?)
     button = @driver.find_element(:id, "expense-bulk-select")
     @driver.action.click(button).perform 
     delete = @driver.find_element(:id, "delete-multi-btn")
     @driver.action.click(delete).perform
     waitDisplayModal = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
     waitDisplayModal.until {@driver.find_element(:class => "bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons")}
     @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[3]/div/div/button[2]").click 
     sleep 3
  end 
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError 
   @driver.find_element(:id, "current_expense_merchant").send_keys "Taxi to work" 
   @driver.find_element(:id, "current_expense_amount").send_keys "50"
   @driver.find_element(:id, "button-add-expense").click
   waitDisplayIconTrash = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 20)
   waitDisplayIconTrash.until {@driver.find_element(:css => ".i.i-pencil.icon")}
 end
end

 after(:all) do
  @driver.quit   
 end
end
```

My problem: When I run this script, appears this in my console:

```
Failure/Error: if(@driver.find_element(:css, ".btn.btn-lg.btn-success.btn-block").displayed?)
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError:
   no such element
     (Session info: chrome=42.0.2311.135)
     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)
```

That is, the IF is not working as I would like. How can I fix it?

CHeers

Comment: Create a function named displayed. Check if element is displayed. If exception is thrown, catch it and return false.

Comment: There is example: http://elementalselenium.com/tips/44-exception-handling

Comment: In fact, I do not want to use rescue because it gives error "Selenium WebDriver :: :: Error :: NoSuchElementError", will run the rescue method "Remove and add new expense". Understand me?

Comment: What you're doing is totally wrong. Each test should ONLY test one thing at a time. Write one test for testing when the button appears and write another for the other case. You shouldn't really use an IF statement at all, if you have to, it's a code smell and you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Arash M - You have an example?

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings
Use the Wait class to explicitly wait for some condition:

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 3)
wait.until { driver.find_element(:css, ".btn.btn-lg.btn-success.btn-block").displayed? }
....
```

Comment: But How I can user IF and ELSE? With this your solution, and if not found the element?

Comment: @Rafael am I right, you are not waiting while element appears. you just want to check element existings? may be this will work: 
if driver.find_elements(:css, ".btn.btn-lg.btn-success.btn-block").present?
...
else
...
end

Comment: find_element will return nil if element doesnt exists and you cant call methos - displayed?. you have to use find_elements instead.